# Tag Synonym Request: [armv8] [aarch64] -> [arm64]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I would like to request that the following tags:

- [armv8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/armv8)
- [aarch64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/aarch64)

be made synonyms of:

- [arm64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/arm64)

---

The official name for the technology in question would by either ARMv8 (with the 64-bit platform being `aarch64`). In order to not confuse users and separate out questions too much, it would be beneficial to merge/synonymize these tags into [arm64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/arm64) until such time as a new ARM platform comes out.

At the time, neither of the two above tags exist in the system.

Once [arm64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/arm64) can refer to multiple technologies, the synonymization can be re-inspected and dealt with accordingly.

Comment: +1 but afaik the only way to create a tag is to tag a question with it, and (afaik) you can't synonymise a non-existant tag

Comment: @Zanna We might not be able to, but I don't think mods are restricted to the same rules as us mere mortals.

Comment: @Zanna: That doesn't prevent one of us from editing a question and adding this new tag to it, thus creating the tag and allowing us to make synonyms of it.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: That would be a complete waste of time, as users need 5 score to suggest/vote on tag synonyms. The arm64 tag is very small, and I doubt anyone has the score threshold needed. Therefore, mod intervention is necessary either way

Comment: @KazWolfe: Sure, but if they don't have mody powers just to puff a tag out of thin air then they could do what I have suggested. Though they probably do given that they are [puffers](http://easyscienceforkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/puffer-fish.jpg)! ;)